# Intuition behind coset equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, intuition

We say $xH = yH$ iff $y^{-1}x \in H$. Writing out the definition of a coset, we have $xH := \{g\in G | g = xh, h \in H\}$, similarly $yH := \{g\in G | g = yh, h \in H\}$. If my logic is correct, $xH = yH$ implies $xh = yh$. So $y^{-1}xh = h$. I am not sure how to jump to $y^{-1}x \in H$ from this statement since we do not know if $H$ is abelian. What is the intuition behind this equality, and how can it be derived?

Comment: The correct statement is $xh_1 = yh_2$, where $h_1,h_2 \in H$ and need not be equal. Then you can note that the cosets $y^{-1}xH$ and $H$ are equal.

Comment: Why do they need not be equal?

Comment: You need some quantifiers. When you write $xh=yh$, are you saying this is true for all $h\in H$? That would not be correct. What is true is that, for any $h_1\in H$, the element $xh_1$ is in $xH$, but since $xH=yH$, that means $xh_1\in yH$, which means there is a $h_2\in H$ for which $xh_1=yh_2$. (And vice-versa.) There is no reason to expect $h_1$ to be the same as $h_2$, so no reason to ask "why do they need not be equal." For instance, if $h\in H$ is not the identity $e$, then $hH=eH$ but $he\ne ee$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$xH=yH$ doesn't imply that $xh=yh$ necessarily. All you can deduce is that $xh_1=yh_2$ for $h_1, h_2 \in H$, ie it need not be the same element.  then $xh_1=yh_2$ is equal to $y^{-1}x=h_2h_1^{-1} \in H$. Remember that $H$ is a subgroup of a group, so $h_1^{-1}$ exists, and by closure $h_2h_1^{-1}$ lies in $H$.

To show that $h$ need not be the same, look at $G=\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$, with $H=\{0,2,4,6,8\}$. Then $1H=\{0,2,4,6,8\}$, $2H=\{0,4,8,2,6\}$. Comparing elements, we have $1.H=2H$. For $h=4 \in H, x=1, y=2$, it doesn't hold that $1.4=2.4$, yet $xH=yH$.